# Segmentation Fault Generating Self Signed Certificate using OpenSSL on OS X

Tags: macos, openssl

I am trying trying to generate a private key and a self signed certificate from my terminal on OS X El Capitan (10.11.1) using the commands below:

```
openssl genrsa 1024 > private.key
openssl req -new -key private.key -out cert.csr
openssl x509 -req -in cert.csr -signkey private.key -out certificate.pem
```

each command that I run returns the following error message:

> Segmentation Fault: 11

If I run `which openssl`, I get the following:

```
/usr/bin/openssl
```

So I assume that it has been installed correctly. Does anybody know what the issue may be ?

Comment: Try running openssl by itself

Comment: Tried it, still gives the same error, so does openssl version

Comment: By any chance, do you have Homebrew or Macports installed?

Comment: I have homebrew installed and tried brew install openssl but still had the same issue